# Does google maps use elevation to calculate travel distance?

Tags: references

For example, lets say I have two parallel roads with starting point and ending point 1 mile apart.

The left hand road is as flat and straight as an arrow.

The right hand road is also straight....but has a series of sine-wave shaped hills and valleys.

Obviously, if I measure using a *Surveyor's wheel*, the second path will be longer, even though both roads are starting and ending a mile apart.

**My question: which measurement does google maps use? Does it account for difference in elevation adding to the travel distance?**

Comment: Your difference there is a difference in road length, not elevation . . .

Comment: Difference in road length due to elevational changes is what OP implies.

Comment: Clearly you guys do not live in SF

Comment: 25 grade in San Francisco http://www.datapointed.net/visualizations/maps/san-francisco/streets-slope/ = about a 3% error

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I doubt it. Since the length of a sloped road would be `sqrt(1+x^2)`-times the length of the flat one (where `x` is the slope). For low values of `x`, this is roughly `1+1/2*x^2`, which is rather low, eg. for a 10 % slope, you get an error of 0.5 %. Not considering the actual lane you drive probably has a similar error.

Comment: also in extreme cases a hilly road is likely to have speed restriction on it which routing algorithms can use to make a choice

Comment: Don't know why this was closed as off topic. I was planning on implementing a similar system for calculating travel distance in a game, and wanted to know how the big boys do it.

Thanks for providing an example in the slope equation though. :).

Answer (score 3):

Even a very steep 10% grade is only 1/2% longer than a flat road covering the same horizontal distance.

Answer (score 0):

It does in cycling mode. Not because of the difference in the distance, but trying to minimise the total climb